# how to show registration success message with bootstrap modal (pop up box) in laravel 5.6

Tags: popup, laravel-5.6

I want to show user registration success message in a bootstrap pop up modal. I am using laravel 5.6 .I am providing my code bellow.

loginController.php: Registration function

```
public function UserRegister(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
    'name'=>'required|max:255',
    'phone'=>'required|min:11|numeric|unique:users',
    'email'=>'unique:users',
    'username'=>'required|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|min:8',
    'pass' => 'required|same:password'
]);
$users = new General_user;
$users->name = $request->input('name');
$users->phone = $request->input('phone');
$users->email = $request->input('email');
$users->username = $request->input('username');
$users->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
$users->reference = $request->input('reference');
$users->save();
return redirect('/user/register')->with('successMsg','Product Information Saved Successfully');
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem with the given code? What does it do? What does not work yet?

Comment: it work's perfectly. It saves user data to users table. But i want to show a message in popup modal box when registration is successful. But i do not know how to do it.Please help